# Не могу разобраться со всплытием

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сама задача такая, при нажатии на label идет проверка на класс, если есть удалить, в ином случае,  добавить. Как мне это реализовать, подскажите. Проблема во всплытие, я уверен.

```
<div class="mens_clothes padding_down_list">
    <h2 class="categories_list">Мужская одежда:</h2>
    <div class="all_mens_categories">
        <div class="list_slide_down_kurtky">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <span class="name_kurtky text_category_clothes">Куртки <span class="text_count_clothes">(47)</span></span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="">
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

---

```
$('ul.list label').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');      
    alert(true);
});
```

---

```
.list li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.in_list {
    padding-left: 13px;
}

.in_list li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.list label{
    display: block;
}


.category_text {
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.categories_list {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.list_slide_down_kurtky label input {
    display: none;
}

.category_text {
    color: #455fc0;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}

.categories_list {
    color: #455fc0;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.list li,
.text_category_clothes, 
.text_count_clothes  
{
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.text_category_clothes {
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #323232;
}

.text_count_clothes {
    color: #a1a1a1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.list input {
    display: none;
}

.list label:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #dadef0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
}

.list label.active:before{
    content: '*';
    text-align: center;
}

.padding_down_list {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.text_count_clothes:after {
    content: '*';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('ul.list label').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.list li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.in_list {
    padding-left: 13px;
}

.in_list li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.list label{
    display: block;
}


.category_text {
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.categories_list {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.list_slide_down_kurtky label input {
    display: none;
}

.category_text {
    color: #455fc0;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
label.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mens_clothes padding_down_list">
    <h2 class="categories_list">Мужская одежда:</h2>
    <div class="all_mens_categories">
        <div class="list_slide_down_kurtky">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>
                    <label class="active">
                        <span class="name_kurtky text_category_clothes">Куртки <span class="text_count_clothes">(47)</span></span><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="">
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема была в том что я использую не тот метод для  проверки, или еще в чем то? @E_K

Comment: @МишаПодлевских, Исправил ответ. Можно использовать и `.toggleClass`, у вас не правильно выбрано событие. Для label используется `.on('change', . . .)`